# PayPal Issue with iOS 6

Tags: iphone, paypal, ios6

I am facing a problem when doing PayPal integration with iOS 6. When I integrate the PayPal lib with my code and build the application, I get the error below after the code is built.

Error:

> DEVELOPER ERROR: This app not using a supported version of the PayPal library.

Comment: Please give some time to PayPal team to update their library for iOS 6 !

Answer (score 1):

There is now a new SDK to support iOS. Please see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/